# Unhandled Exception... Access Violation at Position..while running a kinect application in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, kinect

while running my Application, i get the following error :
Unhandled Exception at 0x0132113D in my_app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation while reading at 0xCDCDCDCD

The thing is : It worked ONCE for me. The Code is not from me, it works fine on the machine from the developer who developed the Code.

What the app does is using a Kinect plugged in the USB port and track your motion.
Is there something wrong with the threads? USB port? I am really not sure what it is.
It's compiling perfectly.

Stack Trace is in german, but you should be able to read it. Thanks!

```
my_app.exe!boost::intrusive_ptr::intrusive_ptr(const boost::intrusive_ptr & rhs) Zeile 91    C++
    my_app.exe!boost::thread::get_thread_info() Zeile 419   C++
    my_app.exe!boost::thread::get_id() Zeile 323    C++
    my_app.exe!boost::thread::join() Zeile 746  C++
    my_app.exe!IModality::stop() Zeile 153  C++
    my_app.exe!NUIEventManager::stop() Zeile 167    C++
    my_app.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Zeile 84   C++
    my_app.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Zeile 536    C
    my_app.exe!mainCRTStartup() Zeile 377   C
    kernel32.dll!764f33aa() Unbekannt
    [Unten angegebene Rahmen sind möglicherweise nicht korrekt und/oder fehlen, keine Symbole geladen für kernel32.dll] 
    ntdll.dll!771a9ef2()    Unbekannt
    ntdll.dll!771a9ec5()    Unbekannt
```

Comment: The hexadecimal value `0xCD` is usually used for uninitialized memory. This means that there probably is an uninitialized pointer somewhere in the code. You should take a look in the functions mentioned in the stack trace to make sure all pointers are initialized.

Comment: Unless you have the code, there isn't much we can do here for you.

Answer (score 1):

> 0xC0000005: Access Violation while reading at 0xCDCDCDCD

You are reading from a pointer that is uninitialized. The 0xCDCDCDCD is filled in by the debugger/compiler (Visual Studio?) to make sure you notice this fact. There are a lot of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) that can be recognized. Someone forgot to initialize a pointer. You will need to check the code to find that bug. "Works on my machine" is not a test for good software. It always works on the developers machine.

Comment: Thanks. I am fairly new to C++ Debugging, what would you say is a good method in finding that bug? setting breakpoints? I tried to use breakpoints and i found the line
m_thread->join();
where the code crashes.

Comment: m_thread seems to be a pointer. Does it have the value 0xCDCDCDCD? Maybe that's your bug already, maybe m_thread was never initialized in the first place.

Comment: sadly not. this is weird, now i get a 
Unhandled Exception at 0x60431770 in  my_app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation (Parameter: 0x00000008)

Comment: You will need to attach the debugger and look at the variables. Some pointer is not what it is supposed to be. Maybe uninitialized, maybe just overwritten by another buggy write behaviour.

Comment: well, the cause is a not existing error handling if something like speech recognition is not initialized. if i deactivate it everything works fine.